# Inputting passport numbers on a website form

Tags: html, forms, web

I am making a website that requires users to enter their passport number.

example passport no (line1): `P<GBRBARNEY<<GABRIELLA<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`

Rules: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport

Ideally I would like a way to ask for the information but not the chevrons.

Has anyone had any experience with this? It seems like a problem others would of had but I've had no luck finding any information/guide.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My client is very keen for users not to have to enter the full 44 digits each time.. :/

Many thanks.

Comment: The less than signs are not part of the passport number (or digits for that matter), they are just markers for the machine readable section. The owners name isn't part of the passport number either. The human readable part of the passport won't show them in the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ask the users to input the text with spaces in between, and then replace multiple spaces with a single space, then split on spaces to get all the segments, and then put the bits together with the chevrons:

```
string inputStr = "P GBRBARNEY GABRIELLA";
string mask = "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);     
inputStr = regex.Replace(inputStr, @" ");
string[] segments = inputStr.Split(' ');
string finalStr = (segments[0] + "<" + segments[1] + "<<" + segments[2] + mask).Substring(0,44);
```

If you have different input formats you need to change the assembly depending on the input types, and perhaps split the input into seperate input fields so you know which segment is which.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @user0000001 the language is c#

Comment: @guymid Yes, but he is asking for a solution that requires you to do it online, e.g. Javascript.

Comment: No I can do that processing at the server so C# is fine. Thanks again for the reply. The only slight issue is working out where the surname ends and the forname begins as this is seperated by two chevrons. For example:
 http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bibliotecapleyades.net%2Fdragons%2Fesp_sociopol_dragondescent2.htm&h=0&w=0&sz=1&tbnid=G6mBl1VX4HQuHM&tbnh=187&tbnw=270&zoom=1&docid=zFSA7v1mdCDE_M&hl=en&ei=Z9FKUsjWM86f7gahhIBA&ved=0CAEQsCU

Comment: If you need the users to input the << then you have an issue because either you do everything as a string and get them to input either <'s or spaces, or you have to separate out the blocks. Given that the format looks varied depending on the passport, I think you might need to put everything in on string. Alternatively you could do it in JavaScript with a box filled with 44 <'s and detect key presses to insert the characters and move one < right when space is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use javascript for it. Check the introduced data (number of characters) into the form and complete it with the amount of ' < ' you need to.